# How can I get the errors of a read operation in c

Tags: c, linux, unix

The following code returns -1, how can I know what's wrong?
get a detailed error or something?

```
if (read(programFile, value, sizeof(FRAME)) == -1) {
        return SYSTEM_CALL;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to look into `errno`, which is a variable set by system calls to indicate an error. You can use the convenience function `perror` to get a human-readable printout.

```
if (read(prog, value, sizeo(FRAME) == -1) {
  perror("read");
  // handle error
}
```

It can return something like `No such file or directory`. Either way its a good practice to use it.

Check out `man errno` and `man perror` for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the [global variable `errno`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/errno.html), as specified in the man page,

> **RETURN VALUES**
>
> > If successful, the number of bytes actually read is returned.  Upon reading end-of-file, zero is returned.  Otherwise, a -1 is returned *and the global variable `errno` is set to indicate the error.*

For example,

```
ssize_t bytesRead = read(...);
if (bytesRead == -1) {
   switch (errno) {
      case EINVAL: return "Invalid FD";
      case EISDIR: return "FD is a directory";
      ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [`read`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read) man page:

> On success, the number of bytes read
>   is returned (zero indicates end of
>   file), and the file  position is
>   advanced by this number.  It is not an
>          error  if  this  number  is smaller than the number of bytes
>   requested;
>          this may happen for example because fewer bytes are actually 
>   available
>          right  now  (maybe  because we were close to end-of-file, or because
>   we
>          are reading from a pipe, or from a terminal),  or  because  read()
>   was
>          interrupted  by  a  signal.  **On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set
>          appropriately**.  In this case it is left unspecified  whether  the 
>   file
>          position (if any) changes.

(my emphasis)

So you can use `errno` and [`strerror`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strerror) for a string description of the error.

Answer (score 0):

`Errno` should be set, for you to check what the error is. More info [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/errno)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <error.h>
#include <errno.h>

if (read(programFile, value, sizeof(FRAME)) == -1) {
    error (0, errno, "Damn it %s", my_string); 
    /* use nonzero as the 1st param to exit after this function */
    return SYSTEM_CALL;
}
```

You can use the `error` function with `errno` with it. This will print the error message and a custom string which you pass as an argument.

Else

```
#include <stdio.h>

if (read(programFile, value, sizeof(FRAME)) == -1) {
    perror ("Damn It!!"); 
    return SYSTEM_CALL;
}
```

Use `perror` to print the error message and a custom string.